# I need to read line from two text files and import to a new file by shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Example: file one  content in file is:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

file two:

```
five
four
three
two
one
```

I want to read from two file inputs to new file by shell script:

new file:

```
5  five
4  four
3  three
2   two
1   one
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: read about `paste` command

Answer (score 1):

Read `man paste`:

```
<bash> paste file1 file2 > newfile
<bash> cat newfile
5       five
4       four
3       three
2       two
1       one
```

Answer (score 1):

With `pr` :

```
$ pr -mts file1 file2 > outputfile
5       five
4       four
3       three
2       two
1       one
```